# How to spread elements horizontally evenly?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` container on my web page with fixed width and it contains form elements for logging in. Below these elements there are a submit button, forgotten password link etc.

It happens the last line elements need fewer width than the box provides. How to spread them evenly? I don't want

- default

```
| A B C           |
```

- centering the line like

```
|      A B C      |
```

- nor table layout

```
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
```

Instead I am looking for some CSS way to achieve:

```
|  A    B    C  |
```

That is:

- put about equal space between all elements
- center the whole thing to avoid the first or last  to the side

**edit:**
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108726/how-to-spread-html-evenly-over-a-line/4108814#4108814) worked best. I created templates for 2 or 3 elements like this:

```
div.spread2evenly > div {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* For IE7 */
    zoom: 1; /* Trigger hasLayout */
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Check my answer on `-moz-inline-box` (or `-moz-inline-stack` ?).  Also, don't forget the caveat that there can't be spaces between the `</div><div>` tags.  Between this and the clear both method, you should have what you need.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this (http://jsfiddle.net/BYEw5/):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div>
</div>

.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    *display: inline; /* For IE7 */
    zoom: 1; /* Trigger hasLayout */
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Since you're dealing with inline-block, you can't have spaces between the tags (ugly, but it works), otherwise the space will be visible.

**Edit 1:**
Here is some more info on the inline-block issues: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/cross-browser-inline-block/, http://www.aarongloege.com/blog/web-development/css/cross-browser-inline-block/.  You may also have to add `display: -moz-inline-box;`.

**Edit 2:**
Also, 33%*3 is not 100%.  If you truly want 100% and don't mind some space between the `div`s you could do:

```
.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    *display: inline; /* For IE7 */
    zoom: 1; /* Trigger hasLayout */
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 32%;
    text-align: center;
}

.container > div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to abstract this solution so it works for an arbitrary number of contained `div`s, not only exactly three `div`s? This would be useful for the scenario when it's not possible to say how many `div`s the `.container div` will have.

Comment: @Abdull a *flexbox layout* with a `justify-content` of (`space-between` or `space-around`) may be the best solution to such scenario: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 70):

[CSS3 flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) have [better browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) now, although you may need to add additional vendor prefixes for [more browser coverage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

#### Modern Approach:

Just change the `display` of the container element to `flex` and then utilize the [`justify-content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to specify how the browser should distribute the space around and between the flex items along the main axis.

In the example below, you will notice that `justify-content: space-around` or `justify-content: space-between` are used to space the elements out evenly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container.space-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container.space-between {  
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<p>Using <code>justify-content: space-around</code>:</p>
<div class="container space-around">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>

<hr />

<p>Using <code>justify-content: space-between</code>:</p>
<div class="container space-between">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is supported by IE11+ and the other major browsers. This is definitely the least hassle method.

Comment: Kudos for a nice easy example of use to use flex.  I've read the various flex how-to's many times and I still don't fully grok it.  This, however, was precisely what I needed, and I learned something.  +1

Answer (score 30):

how about `text-align:justify;` ?

Comment: Why did peopel downvote this?  This solution doesn't require any CSS tricks and works.

Comment: this is by far the best solution. The only thing to remember is that you need the line to break. You can to that with a pseudo-element with `height: 0` and `width: 100%`

Comment: Even in 2020 it lacks the browser support.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an ancient question but if someone still happens to look for this, there now is an even easier option using flexboxes: `justifiy-content: space-evenly`. The name is pretty self explanatory. Here [a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Values)

```
 .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly the approach I was looking for. If someone doesn't want the space before the first and after the last element, use `space-between` instead ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your exact HTML is but try this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9FqG/

```
<div class="test">
    <a href="">A</a>
    <a href="">B</a>
    <a href="">C</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.clear {
   clear:both;   
}

.test {
   width:350px;
   text-align:center;
   border:1px solid #ff0000
}

.test a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

Comment: That one works pretty well! But how to format things like the submit button -- that one shouldn't get 33% wide.

Comment: Any idea how to compute the % number? Anything else then doing it with JS?

Comment: 1/n, where n is the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
<style type="text/css">

#container {
    width: 210px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#container .part {
    width: 68px; /*(210 / 3 - borders)*/
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.clear {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    clear: left;
}

</style>
```

And then the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="part">A</div>
    <div class="part">B</div>
    <div class="part">C</div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I only added borders so you could see what the CSS was doing.

Comment: +1, Nice code. I just would suggest a mix, in order to avoid problems if padding, margin or border are going to inner elements. Using box-sizing property, and perhaps width as percentage.

Comment: Dave, I definitely agree. I meant this answer to be a starting point, not a perfect solution. I usually leave the finer details to the poster to give them something to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to perform some hover effect and `justify-content: space-between` wasn't very clean. This helped for me.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="flex: 1 1 auto"> A </div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 auto"> B </div>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 auto"> C </div>
</div>
```

(I originally got this answer from a different S.O. answer a very long time ago. Pardon me for not mentioning original credit, as I don't know)