# Rounding width aka spread divs evenly

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling spreading fives divs evenly inside a resizeable div. I have looked at [How to spread elements evenly (horizonatly)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108726/how-to-spread-html-evenly-over-a-line) but cant get it to work :-(

The problem seems to be that even thoug my div width is set to 20% the last element is wrapped onto the next line if the surrounding divs width is not dividable by 5.

My css is this

```
#exposureSummaryContainer > div { width: 20%;display: inline-block;}
```

and my html:

```
<div id="exposureSummaryContainer">
    <div>1.000.000</div>
    <div>1.000.000</div>
    <div>1.000.000</div>
    <div>1.000.000</div>
    <div>1.000.000</div>
</div>
```

How do I ensure that all five elements stay on the same line?

I made this http://jsfiddle.net/GTwFb/ to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left;`

```
#exposureSummaryContainer > div { width: 20%;display: inline-block; float:left; background:red}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GTwFb/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a whitespace you don't see, if you removed it,

<`div id="exposureSummaryContainer"><div>1.000.000</div><div>1.000.000</div><div>1.000.000</div><div>1.000.000</div><div>1.000.000</div></div>`

it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the best looking way.. but its working

```
#exposureSummaryContainer { width: 100%; display: table; }
#exposureSummaryContainer > div { width: 20%;display: table-cell;}
```

You can edit the `width` to a specific size

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the physical space on the markup amongs div elements when their display is `inline-block`, so a workaround is the following:

```
#exposureSummaryContainer {
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-spacing: -3px;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
}

#exposureSummaryContainer > div { 
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `float: left;` property

This works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/GTwFb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Well I would you the trick of table:

```
<table style="width:whateveryouwant">
<tr>
<td style="width:20%"><div>1.000.000</div></td>
<td style="width:20%"><div>1.000.000</div></td>
<td style="width:20%"><div>1.000.000</div></td>
<td style="width:20%"><div>1.000.000</div></td>
<td style="width:20%"><div>1.000.000</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This works for me all the time ^_^