# Margin depending on quantity of elements

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 960px width container and buttons there. I want to make buttons like this:

960px width
/--------------\
[btn]margin[btn]

and

960px width
/---------------\
[btn]m[btn]m[btn]

I want to make the margin auto setting.

Comment: did you mean that you want to align buttons to the center

Comment: @geeksal no, i want to make margin depending on quantity of buttons

Comment: this might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108726/how-to-spread-html-evenly-over-a-line

Comment: just see the answer and then let me know @fox

Comment: @aless80 but is this possible to make it without giving percent? (I have to 100 / qty)

Comment: put the 100% div inside another div that spans 100 / qty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
  <button>button4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use flexbox layout

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
  </div>
```

**Second snippet**

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
  <button>button3</button>
  <button>button4</button>
  </div>
```

For complete guide visit:  [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)