# HTML - evenly spreading buttons horizontally

Tags: html

Have a fairly frustrating situation I'd love some help with if it is at all possible. Our company is using an incredibly outdated CMS for one of our internal sites, in of which; we can't use custom style sheets.

Because of this, I'm trying to simply evenly spread some 5 buttons horizontally, but am really struggling to do so. Any help is really appreciated:

```
<div align="center">        
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>        
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>        
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>        
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>        
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>    
</div>
```

Comment: Here is an answer to spreading <div> elements. This may work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108726/how-to-spread-elements-evenly-horizonatly

Comment: @ShahidulIslam I think he cannot make use of CSS.